# Jumping into a block in C

Tags: c, static, goto

If I jump into a block like in this example, jumping "over" the declarations,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int counter = 0;
  goto jump;
  {
    static int st = -9;
    int au = -9;
jump:
    printf("st = %d\n", st);
    printf("au = %d\n", au);
    au++;
    st++;
    counter++;
  }

  if(counter < 10) goto jump;

  return 0;
}
```

I can compile it with `gcc --std=c89 -pedantic`.

It seems that you can't really jump "over" declarations: the variables are still *declared,* even if the lines in which those declarations are made are ***never*** reached.

But somehow you can jump over definitions...

1. `st` as a static variable gets initialized with the value -9 and counts up to 0.
2. `au` gets initialized with the value 0 and counts up to 9.

Is 1. and/or 2. a behavior which is necessitated by the C standard?

Comment: MY EYES Please don't use goto, it's a really bad practice. At the beginning of c it was used quite a lot due to the migration from assembly code, this resulted in so called "spaghetti code" , and programs which were practically incomprehensible. I know this might be a question out of curiosity but don't use goto

Comment: `au` is uninitialized after the jump; your printf statement causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mr.Branch Goto is NOT a bad practice. We should avoid abuse goto. In linux kernel, there're so many goto, goto can make code clearly in many situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C static variables such as `st` are initialized at program startup before `main()` is called, even for static variables that are scoped to a function or block.  Jumping past the declaration/initializer does not affect this, so for this particular scenario, no undefined, unspecified, or indeterminate behavior occurs.

For an automatic variable, such as `au`, the initialization occurs when the declaration is reached in the execution of the block.  Since the `goto` jumps past that part of the block's execution, the value of `au` remains indeterminate, and it is undefined behavior to use the variable's value in that situation without first setting it to some determinate value.

Note that several details of this are different in C++. For example, the C++ standard says that a program is ill-formed if it jumps past a declaration unless that declaration is for a POD type and the declaration does not contain an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes, and (2) Yes, it will have an indeterminate value.
References: [C Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization), [C++ Default Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)

In C, the scope of a non-`static` variable is defined as being from the point the variable is declared to the end of its enclosing block, but its initializer is treated as a statement. A stack variable that has not been set to a value will have an indeterminate value, similarly to how a heap variable (allocated with `malloc()`) will have whatever junk value happens to be in the assigned memory location.

On the other hand, a `static` variable is always declared (but is only accessible within its own block) and is filled with its initializing value essentially as soon as the program starts, so that it will have that value as soon as it comes in scope.

Here is some hand-written assembly that shows how the C code might directly translate. An optimizer will make changes to make the code smaller or faster, and a compiler would add some extra tags and notes for debugging, tracking, and other purposes. I may not have the syntax exactly right, but it's close enough for our purposes.

```
.data
st:            WORD    -9           ;declaration and initialization of st
str1:        STRING    "st = %d\n"
str2:        STRING    "au = %d\n"

.text
main:
push   ebp           ;save base pointer
mov    ebp, esp      ;set base pointer to current stack position

;adjust base pointer for use in referring to function parameters and local variables
add    ebp, 12       ;4 bytes for old base pointer
                     ;4 bytes for argv
                     ;4 bytes for argc
sub    esp, 8        ;reserve 4 bytes for counter (declaration)
                     ;reserve 4 bytes for au(declaration)

mov    [esp], 0      ;initialize of counter

jmp    jump          ;goto jump label

mov    -20[ebp], -9  ;initialize au (THIS IS SKIPPED OVER AND IGNORED)

jump:                ;label, same as in C

push   [st]          ;parameters for printf
push   str1
call   printf        ;call to printf function

push   -20[ebp]      ;parameters for second call to printf
push   str2
call   printf        ;call printf

inc    -20[ebp]      ;increment au
inc    [st]          ;increment st
inc    -16[ebp]      ;increment counter

sub    -16[ebp], 10  ;if(counter == 10)
je     jump          ;jump if equal to jump label

mov    eax, 0        ;set return value

add    esp, 20       ;clean up stack
pop    ebp           ;restore base pointer
ret                  ;return from main
```

Notice especially that `st` is defined and given a value in the code itself, while `au` is saved on the stack, and only gets its value when the code assigns it one.

---

If `au` is instead made a global variable (i.e. *thread-local*) with no initializer, the compiler will put `au` into the `.data` section with the default value for the type, in which case the code would change like this:

```
.data
;... other data lines
au:            WORD    0            ;declaration and uninitialized (default) value of au

.text
;... other instruction code lines
sub    esp, 4        ;reserve 4 bytes for only counter

;... other instruction code lines
jmp    jump          ;goto jump label
mov    [au], -9      ;assign au (still skipped and ignored)
jump:                ;label, same as in C
;... rest of program (references to au use [au] instead of -20[ebp]
```

Comment: "A stack variable that has not been set to a value is usually pre-initialized to zero." is wrong;  nor is it implementation-defined as you say in the first paragraph.

Comment: @M.M You are right. Goes to show what I get for going off of memory. I've looked up the information and edited my answer to correct the statements.